# Using "wegen" at an reception/information desk to ask for information

Tags: question, informal

would it be correct to use "wegen X" as an equivalent to "for X" at a reception desk.

For example "Hi, for the blood test, should I...". Would it be equivalent to "Hallo, wegen dem Bluttest, sollte man links oder rechts gehen?. .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *wegen* requires the genitive, so it must be

> Hallo, wegen de**s** Bluttest**s**, ...

For the question which word to use, yes, you can use either *für X* or *wegen Y*, both would be correct. Which one would sound more natural would depend a bit un the exact wording.

The version with wegen would be the best choice as an introduction to another complete sentence. Examples:

> Wegen des Bluttests: Darf ich da vorher etwas essen, oder muss ich nüchtern sein?
>   (For the blood test: may I eat something before or do I need to have an empty stomach?)
>
> Wegen des Bluttests sollte ich mich bei Doktor Müller melden.
>   (With respect to the blood test I should report to Doktor Müller)
>
> Wegen des Bluttests hätte ich da noch ein paar Fragen
>   (With regard to the blood test, I still have some questions)

In your concrete example with direction, *wegen* is also possible, but I would probably rather say

> Für den Bluttest, muss ich da nach rechts oder links?
>   or even
>   Zum Bluttest, muss ich da nach rechts oder links?

But that is a matter of style rather than a matter of right or wrong.

Comment: I know officially it must be genitive. But here in Franconia people don't say that. We all say *wegen dem*...

Comment: @somega I just needed strong self-discipline to refrain from making a snarky remark about the "German" the people in the south are speaking...

Comment: Andererseits - man gewöhnt sich an allem, sogar am Dativ

Comment: Oder an unnötige Kommentare im Allgemeinen :)

Comment: @Volker Landgraf: In spoken German you will very often come across _wegen + Dativ_. Okay, it's not 'standard German', but as far as I can see it would be wrong to say that _wegen + Dativ_ is wrong. In my region and in the given situation "wegen des Bluttests" sounds rather bookish. I live in the Ruhr area. The question reminds me the ongoing dispute whether it has to be _Schraubendreher_ or _Schraubenzieher_, as most people say.